# Chromatic Number and Chromatic Polynomial of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm studying chromatic numbers and chromatic polynomials of graphs at the moment and I know the subtle connection between the two:

Let $G$ be a graph, $\chi(G)$ be it's chromatic number and $p_G(x)$ be it's chromatic polynomial. Then $\chi(G)=\min\{k:p_G(k)>0\}$.

However, I'm wondering if we can say more than just that. I'm looking at whether there are any proofs or any counterexamples for my following claim:

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are graphs with $|G|=|H|$ and $e(G)=e(H)$. Then is the following true: $\chi(G)>\chi(H)\iff p_G(x)>p_H(x)$ for sufficiently large $x$.

I've managed to construct something which may be a counterexample but I don't quite seem to understand why (as in it doesn't intuitively seem to make sense).

My example:
$G=C_3+e$ and $H=C_4$. Both have 4 edges and 4 vertices and $\chi(G)=3>2=\chi(H)$.

$p_G(x)=x^4-4x^3+6x^2-3x$ and $p_H(x)=x^4-4x^3+5x^2-2x-1$ which shows that $p_H(x)>p_G(x)$ for large $x$. I obtained $p_G(x)$ by using the formula known for cycles and obtained $p_H(x)$ by using the recurrence relation to reduce $H$ to $C_3$.

I may have made a careless mistake so I'd appreciate if somebody could check these for me.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be overlapping a lot with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390513/graphs-which-satisfy-chig-chih-and-p-gx-p-hx).

First of all, you have made some mistake in your computation (it is easy to spot that $p_H$ has a mistake: it cannot have a non-zero constant term). For the $G$ and $H$ you defined, the correct polynomials are
$$ p_G(x) = x^4 - 4 x^3 + 5 x^2 - 2 x$$
$$ p_H(x) = x^4 - 4 x^3 + 6 x^2 - 3 x$$ 
So $p_G(x) < p_H(x)$ when $x$ is large.

Secondary, what you propose cannot work in either direction. See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2737114/14794) to the question I have linked above. The large $x$ behavior of $p_G(x) - p_H(x)$ is not related to which one has the largest chromatic number, but to which one has the largest girth.